# Can I substitute a submit input element with an image to postback a form without using javascript?

Tags: html, forms, postback

I've seen [buttons](http://www.grsites.com/) that have some nice shape. I downloaded a couple of them to try on my application. I was expecting to get an image to be used as background for my buttons and textboxes. But, The downloaded file contains 2 images and a script. It looks to me like those shaped controls are aimed at replacing the html buttons and textboxes.

If they are supposed to take the place of the regular buttons, how can I post a form with an image? With javascript that feasable. But, is it possible to get samething without javascript?

Thanks for helping

Comment: Are you using ASP.Net? (the tag `postback` makes me think about it)

Comment: @CMS: sorry, I should have said just post. I'm using ASP.NET MVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can style buttons:

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Go!"/>
<input type="button" class="button" value="Cancel!"/>
```

And CSS:

```
.button{
     background: #FFF url('images/button-bg.jpg') repeat-x;
     color: #000;
     font: 1.0em Tahoma;
     border: 1px solid #D4D4D4;
     cursor: pointer; /* Change cursor to 'hand' when hovering the button */
}
.button:hover{
     background: #EEE url('images/button-hover-bg.jpg') repeat-x;
     border: 1px solid #666;
}
```

Example of what the above style will get you:

[Man she's pretty http://img714.imageshack.us/img714/5773/84220208.png](http://img714.imageshack.us/img714/5773/84220208.png)

Note that the text `value` of the buttons will still be shown, allowing your to keep your form accessible.

Such buttons retain their utility while being far more beautiful. Much like women with makeup.

More resources: http://speckyboy.com/2009/05/27/22-css-button-styling-tutorials-and-techniques/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`<input type="image"/>`](http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms14.htm) to do this:

```
<input type="image" src="your-fancy-button.png" alt="Submit"/>
```